# DeepCopy of a java.util.AbstractQueue

Tags: java, data-structures, deep-copy

I need to to create a deep copy of an instance of `java.util.AbstractQueue` because the creation of that queue is rather slow (e,g. `getTextBlocks(doc)`) and I want to reuse that object in an iterator.

```
AbstractQueue<TextBlock> cache= getTextBlocks(doc);
```

I have tried

```
AbstractQueue aq = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(cache);
```

but that does obviously not work since the underlying objects are obviously still the same. Is there any way to do a deep copy of that structure? I used `Collections.copy(a,b)` from the Apache Commons collection but that only works on Lists, not on AbstractQueue as the signature shows:

```
public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src)
```

Comment: iterate over the queue and clone each element?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the Cloner library, who has rather good performance :

https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning